# How do I save many-to-many relationships in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations

I have the following setup in my rails app:
A user registers and he chooses from a set of check boxes for Music Styles.

The Music Styles are only 4 right now but should be extendable. I'd like to have a list of MusicStyles that I can extend and change easily.

My approach would be to create a model 'MusicStyles' and a model 'UserMusicStyles' and then use a has_many_through association similar to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_music_styles
  has_many :music_styles, :through => :user_music_styles
end

class UserMusicStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :music_style
end

class MusicStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :music_styles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_music_styles
end
```

Now, during registration I would do something like MusicStyle.all.each do |m| ... to display the checkboxes but how do I save it to the database correctly in the user controller?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <!-- User stuff -->
  ...
  <% MusicStyle.all.each do |m| %>
    <%= check_box_tag('user[music_style_ids][]', m.id, @user.music_styles.include?(m)) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: will Rails automatically know how to save that? My question was about how to process that in the controller to save it correctly. If it's this simple, I'm gonna go ahead and give it a try - thanks!

Comment: You have to set `attr_accessible :music_style_ids` in your `User` model, but then Rails should know how to automatically save it.

Comment: Follow-Up: When the user registers, I want all 4 boxes to be checked by default but then when he edits his profile and comes back to the form, only those should be checked that he checked when he signed up - how would I do that?